# How do I add JSON array entries into a JSON object using jq?

Tags: json, jq

I am writing a script that is meant to clean up Route53 records, so I want to add entries in an array to a JSON object as below

outer.json

```json
{
  "Comment": "Delete record sets for $cluster_name",
  "Changes": [
    {
      "Action": "DELETE",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

records.json

```json
[
  {
    "Name": "abcde_svcx.$cluster_name.domain.com.",
    "Type": "TXT",
    "TTL": 300,
    "ResourceRecords": [
      {
        "Value": "\"heritage=external-dns,external-dns/owner=$cluster_name,external-dns/resource=service/svcx/svcx-cluster\""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "svcx.$cluster_name.domain.com.",
    "Type": "A",
    "AliasTarget": {
      "HostedZoneId": "123456789",
      "DNSName": "some-value.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com.",
      "EvaluateTargetHealth": true
    }
  }
]
```

I would like to have an output that looks like below:

output.json

```json
{
  "Comment": "Delete record sets for $cluster_name",
  "Changes": [
    {
      "Action": "DELETE",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "Name": "abcde_svcx.$cluster_name.domain.com.",
        "Type": "TXT",
        "TTL": 300,
        "ResourceRecords": [
          {
            "Value": "\"heritage=external-dns,external-dns/owner=$cluster_name,external-dns/resource=service/svcx/svcx-cluster\""
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Action": "DELETE",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "Name": "svcx.$cluster_name.domain.com.",
        "Type": "A",
        "AliasTarget": {
          "HostedZoneId": "123456789",
          "DNSName": "some-value.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com.",
          "EvaluateTargetHealth": true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is this something that can be done in a shell script using jq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `|=` the `.Changes` array by adding to its `first` item's `ResourceRecordSet` field the second file's array items `input[]`:

```sh
jq '.Changes |= [first | .ResourceRecordSet += input[]]' outer.json records.json
```

```json
{
  "Comment": "Delete record sets for $cluster_name",
  "Changes": [
    {
      "Action": "DELETE",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "Name": "abcde_svcx.$cluster_name.domain.com.",
        "Type": "TXT",
        "TTL": 300,
        "ResourceRecords": [
          {
            "Value": "\"heritage=external-dns,external-dns/owner=$cluster_name,external-dns/resource=service/svcx/svcx-cluster\""
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Action": "DELETE",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "Name": "svcx.$cluster_name.domain.com.",
        "Type": "A",
        "AliasTarget": {
          "HostedZoneId": "123456789",
          "DNSName": "some-value.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com.",
          "EvaluateTargetHealth": true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0XLMizylKA)

Note: If `outer.json`'s `ResourceRecordSet` is always empty, you may as well just make an assignment `=` instead of an updating addition `+=`.